# How to display svg as image with background-color given in URL

Tags: php, css, svg, discord.js, data-uri

Helo,
I'm trying to create discord bot with some cool options and one of them is a color command where I want to display a thumbnail with background-color from argument.

I've tried to set this as thumbnail
`data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle r='50' cx='50' cy='50' fill='%23" + hex + "'/%3E%3C/svg%3E`
where **hex** is given from command argument.

The problem was that Discord.js uses URL for a thumbnail so I thought I can create some kind of api to display svg element colored with color from the link, but I can't find useful informations how to do that.

For example: `mywebsite.com/color/ffffff` will display white svg logo as image.

Comment: generate the data URL on the fly with the appropriate colours in it.

Comment: A Data URL (`data:`) *is* a URL.  So you may need to elaborate on why it didn't work.  Do you mean that discord.js only accepts `http:` and `https:` URLs?